# jQuery on click for dynamic element triggering when not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that I am appending to the page. When that button is clicked, it should run some code.

Instead of triggering only when that button is clicked, any clicks on the page triggers it.

I've been able to replicate the issue with only a few lines of code, see the JSFiddle linked.

```
var myButton = '<div id="myButton">Do Not Click Me</div>';
$('#parent').html(myButton);

jQuery(document).on('click', jQuery('#myButton'), function (e) {
    alert('marco');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aj4u1y9n/

How can I make the alert run only when the button is clicked?

Comment: `.on('click', '#myButton', function (e) {...`

Comment: Why do you switch between `jQuery` and `$`?

Comment: @j08691 In my actual code I have to use jQuery to prevent a conflict with another library.

Comment: It seems some jack@ss thinks that our jQuery stinks, I'm +1 everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a jQuery selector here:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', jQuery('#myButton'), function (e)
```

Instead, do:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function (e)
```

Example:

```js
var myButton = '<div id="myButton">Do Not Click Me</div>';
$('#parent').html(myButton);

$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(e) {
  alert('marco');
});
```

```css
#myButton {
  background: #8888ff;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 4em;
  margin-left: 4em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

By the way, your code could be simplified to this:

```js
var myButton = '<div id="myButton">Do Not Click Me</div>';
$('#parent').html(myButton);

$('#myButton').click(function() {
  alert('marco');
});
```

```css
#myButton {
  background: #8888ff;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 4em;
  margin-left: 4em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

**BTW**, don't switch between the selectors `jQuery` and `$`, use one or the other.

Comment: It appeared like somebody downvoted the question and all three answers at once.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the click listener, you actually listen for clicks on the whole document. Have a look at the jQuery API:

- https://api.jquery.com/on/ or
- https://api.jquery.com/click/ as the shorter version

for more information.

You can achieve what you wish like that:

```
var $myButton = $('<div id="myButton">Do Not Click Me</div>');
$myButton.click(function (e) {
    alert('marco');
});
$('#parent').append($myButton);
```

Explanation: You can add the click listener before you insert the element into the DOM. Searching it again in the DOM for adding a click handler is just unnecessary.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkbczLug/